# Change how the PDF filename is formatted?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, pdf

In the Commerce plugin, there are several ways to download a PDF of a specific order.

However, the default formatting of the PDF filename isn't very helpful...

> ⁠⁠⁠⁠Order-14ef9b78dae6893cd2ca75ec047ed9a0.pdf

**Is there any way to control the formatting of PDF receipt filenames?**

Comment: Will be possible to customise the name in a future release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently not a native way to change this format, but it is planned for a future release.

In the meantime as a workaround, you can listen to the [onBeforeSaveOrder](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onbeforesaveorder) event and change the order number to whatever format you want.  A by-product of that is that the PDF receipt filename should change to your format as well.